# Bootstrap carousel - pause when YouTube video played

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, carousel

I have some embedded YouTube videos in my Bootstrap carousel.  By default, the carousel advances automatically, but I'd like to to pause when a video is playing.

Is there a trick to detecting when the video is playing?  I'd like to do it without using the YouTube API if possible (each carousel has an arbitrary number of videos, and I'd like not to create instances of every video).

**Edit: Final Design**

I created an overlap over the video:

```
.video_mask{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:275px;
  z-index:25;
  opacity:0;
}
```

When I click on the mask, I set the corresponding iframe to autoplay, hide the mask, and pause the carousel:

```
 $('.video_mask').click(function(){
    iframe = $(this).closest('.item').find('iframe');
    iframe_source = iframe.attr('src');
    iframe_source = iframe_source + "?autoplay=1"
    iframe.attr('src', iframe_source);
    // hide the mask
    $(this).toggle();
    // stop the slideshow
    $('.projectOverviewCarousel').carousel('pause');
  });
```

When the user clicks on the carousel controls, it resets all masks and iframe urls:

```
  $('.projectOverviewCarousel').on('slide', function(){
    var iframeID = getID($(this).find('iframe').attr("id"));
    // stop iframe from playing
    if(iframeID != undefined){
      callPlayer(iframeID, 'stopVideo');
    }
    // turn on all masks
    $('.video_mask').show();
    // reset src of all videos
    $('.projectOverviewCarousel').find('iframe').each(function(key, value){
      url = $(this).attr('src');
      if(url.indexOf("autoplay")>0){
        new_url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
        $(this).attr('src', new_url);
      }
    });
```

Some things to check out for: make sure the controls for the bootstrap carousel have a z-index greater than the mask (so the person can still progress the slideshow manually).

Hope this is useful to someone else!

Comment: you could place an overlay over the iframe that when clicked, pauses the carousel and redirects the iframe to the same video but with autoplay on. Not quite sure on how you would initiate it continueing after though.

Comment: could you explain in more detail how I might do the last part (redirecting the iframe to the same video with autoplay)?

Comment: `theiframe.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?autoplay=1"`

Comment: Instead of editing your own question, add an answer with your solution and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created an overlap over the video:

```
.video_mask{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:275px;
  z-index:25;
  opacity:0;
}
```

When I click on the mask, I set the corresponding iframe to autoplay, hide the mask, and pause the carousel:

```
 $('.video_mask').click(function(){
    iframe = $(this).closest('.item').find('iframe');
    iframe_source = iframe.attr('src');
    iframe_source = iframe_source + "?autoplay=1"
    iframe.attr('src', iframe_source);
    // hide the mask
    $(this).toggle();
    // stop the slideshow
    $('.projectOverviewCarousel').carousel('pause');
  });
```

When the user clicks on the carousel controls, it resets all masks and iframe urls:

```
  $('.projectOverviewCarousel').on('slide', function(){
    var iframeID = getID($(this).find('iframe').attr("id"));
    // stop iframe from playing
    if(iframeID != undefined){
      callPlayer(iframeID, 'stopVideo');
    }
    // turn on all masks
    $('.video_mask').show();
    // reset src of all videos
    $('.projectOverviewCarousel').find('iframe').each(function(key, value){
      url = $(this).attr('src');
      if(url.indexOf("autoplay")>0){
        new_url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
        $(this).attr('src', new_url);
      }
    });
```

Some things to check out for: make sure the controls for the bootstrap carousel have a z-index greater than the mask (so the person can still progress the slideshow manually).

Hope this is useful to someone else!

Comment: The bootstrap carousel slide event is now namespaced - new event name is "slide.bs.carousel".

Comment: Just adding to David's comment - you should replace $('.projectOverviewCarousel').on('slide', function(){
with
$('.projectOverviewCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

Answer (score 0):

The new **Carousel 2**, which was released during April 2016, added more support for video playback. Check out [their website](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/), especially the [video documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/video.html).

Here is a code example from their website:

#### Setup

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    merge:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    video:true,
    lazyLoad:true,
    center:true,
    responsive:{
        480:{
            items:2
        },
        600:{
            items:4
        }
    }
})
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="3"><a class="owl-video" href="https://vimeo.com/23924346"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="1"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpxsRwnRwCQ"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBu_jxT1PkA"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="1"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy18DJwy5lI"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3jLkJrhHKQ"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="3"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3J4VxWIM6s"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="1"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fhoIate4qI"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF_kj2ojZaE"></a></div>
</div>
```