# Slider is moving while playing the video

Tags: jquery, html, video, slider

I am using bootstrap slider.

In my slider i have some videos with text. There is no init function to initialize the slider. The class names are enough. Here is my code

```
<div id="home-slide" style="width:920px;margin:0 auto;height:330px;">
                        <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide" style="height:330px;">
                             <div class="carousel-inner container">

                              <div class="active item row-fluid row_padder vid_slider">
                                    <div class="feed_para">
                                        <img src="about/images/new/quote.png" />
                                        <p class="feedback_para"> I got my first job in 2 months, with better industry knowledge, now i am placed in a dream company <span style="color:#2C5F96;font-size:19px;">Mahendran, kanchipuram</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="feed_video">
                                    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8Scz9O4cdxs?version=3&enablejsapi=1?rel=0" id="ContentBody_frameVideo" width="405" height="250" frameborder="0" style="background-color:white;"></iframe>

                                    </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="item row-fluid row_padder vid_slider">
                                    <div class="feed_para">
                                        <img src="about/images/new/quote.png" />
                                        <p class="feedback_para"> We learnt latest technologies,got hands on experience and got job through CODEREADY placements <span style="color:#2C5F96;font-size:19px;">2011 batch</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="feed_video">
                                    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/l2PAPTXj1Vs?version=3&enablejsapi=1?rel=0" id="ContentBody_frameVideo" width="405" height="250" frameborder="0" style="background-color:white;"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                              </div>

                               <div class="item row-fluid row_padder vid_slider">
                                    <div class="feed_para">
                                        <img src="about/images/new/quote.png" />
                                        <p class="feedback_para"> I am very grateful to them. To show my gratefulness, i have shared my experience to all my friends. <span style="color:#2C5F96;font-size:19px;">Rajeshwaran</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="feed_video">
                                    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aP9XQLv5jxw?version=3&enablejsapi=1?rel=0" id="ContentBody_frameVideo" width="405" height="250" frameborder="0" style="background-color:white;"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The script i am using is

```
<script src="http://www.indiainternetready.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3"></script> <script src="http://www.indiainternetready.com/wp-content/themes/iir/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The problem i am facing is when i am playing the video/Mouse over flash content 
the slider doesn't stop. How to make the slider stop while playing the video/mouse over on flash part ?

Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can pause your carousel by doing something like this:

```
$('#myCarousel1 .item').click(function () {
    $('#myCarousel1').carousel('pause');
});
```

or you could initialise your carousel with the pause option:

```
$('#myCarousel1').carousel({
    pause: 'hover'
});
```

Comment: I have to choose only one ??

Comment: On clicking the video if i will remove the cursor then it doesn't stop. but mouse over is working

Comment: I wonder if you have to put the click onto the iframe then - [have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241569/bootstrap-carousel-pause-when-youtube-video-played), they seem to have created a masque that you click to play the video and pause the carousel at the same time